# "The plugin is registered in the main program but not functioning."

Tags: java, spigot

"I have a question. My plugin has two files, `FireballPlugin.java` (main program) and `BlockReset.java` (subprogram). However, when I write `Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockReset(), this);` in the main program to register `BlockReset.java`, `Intellij` does not show any errors, but it doesn't work in the game. However, if I merge Fireball.java and `BlockReset.java` together, it works. What could be the issue?"

Here is my code:

[main program]:

```java
package com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin;

import com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.BlockExplode.BlockReset;
import com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.PlayerResistance.AntiFire;
import org.bukkit.*;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.*;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.ProjectileHitEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;


public class FireballPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {


    private double horizontalKnockback;
    private double verticalKnockback;
    private double Speed;
    private int Power;
    private boolean Incendiary;
    private boolean comboMode;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private boolean destroyBlocks;
    private boolean fallDamage;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new GiveItemWhenJoin(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new AntiFire(),this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockReset(),this);
        loadConfig();
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "FireballPlugin has been enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.RED + "FireballPlugin has been disabled!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void Fireball(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.FIREBALL) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection().normalize();
                    Fireball fireball = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), Fireball.class);
                    fireball.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    fireball.setShooter(player);
                    fireball.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                    fireball.setYield(1 + Power);
                }
            }
        }


        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.FIREBALL && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void SmallFireball(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BLAZE_POWDER) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection();
                    SmallFireball smallFireball = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), SmallFireball.class);
                    smallFireball.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    smallFireball.setShooter(player);
                    smallFireball.setYield(Power);
                    smallFireball.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                }
            }
        }

        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.BLAZE_POWDER && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void WitherSKull(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.SKULL_ITEM) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection();
                    WitherSkull witherSkull = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), WitherSkull.class);
                    witherSkull.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    witherSkull.setShooter(player);
                    witherSkull.setYield(Power);
                    witherSkull.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                }
            }
        }

        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.SKULL_ITEM && player.getItemInHand().getDurability() == 1&& player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }


    @EventHandler
    public void onTntLaunch(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
            if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
                 Material heldMaterial = getHeldMaterial(player);
                if (heldMaterial == Material.TNT) {
                    if(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                        TNT(player);
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
            if (material == Material.TNT && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")){
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
    }
    private Material getHeldMaterial(Player player) {
        ItemStack heldItem = player.getItemInHand();
        return heldItem.getType();
    }

    private void TNT(Player player) {
        TNTPrimed tnt = player.getWorld().spawn(player.getLocation(), TNTPrimed.class);
        tnt.setFuseTicks(50);
        double tntSpeed = 1.3;
        tnt.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(tntSpeed));
        tnt.setYield(1 + Power);
        tnt.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof TNTPrimed) {
            handleTNTExplosion(event);
        } else if (event.getEntity() instanceof Fireball) {
            handleFireballExplosion(event);
        } else if(event.getEntity() instanceof WitherSkull){
            handleWitherSkullExplosion(event);
        }
    }

    private void handleTNTExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }

    private void handleFireballExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }
    private void handleWitherSkullExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof Player && event.getCause() == EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause.FALL) {
            if (!fallDamage) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadConfig() {

        saveDefaultConfig();

        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();

        horizontalKnockback = config.getDouble("fireball.knockback.horizontalKnockback",5.0);
        verticalKnockback = config.getDouble("fireball.knockback.verticalKnockback",-2.5);
        Speed =config.getDouble("fireball.Speed",1.5);
        Power = config.getInt("fireball.Power",3);
        Incendiary = config.getBoolean("fireball.Incendiary",false);
        comboMode = config.getBoolean("Combo",false);
        destroyBlocks = config.getBoolean("fireball.destroyBlocks" , false);
        fallDamage = config.getBoolean("fallDamage", false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("fireball")) {
            if (args.length == 8) {
                try {
                    double f1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
                    double f2 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
                    double f3 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
                    int f4 = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
                    boolean f5 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[4]);
                    boolean f6 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[5]);
                    boolean f7 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[6]);
                    boolean f8 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[7]);

                    horizontalKnockback = f1;
                    verticalKnockback = f2;
                    Speed = f3;
                    Power = f4;
                    Incendiary = f5;
                    comboMode = f6;
                    destroyBlocks = f7;
                    fallDamage = f8;

                    setMaxNoDamageTicks(comboMode);

                    FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
                    config.set("fireball.knockback.horizontalKnockback", horizontalKnockback);
                    config.set("fireball.knockback.verticalKnockback", verticalKnockback);
                    config.set("fireball.Speed", Speed);
                    config.set("fireball.Power", Power);
                    config.set("fireball.Incendiary", Incendiary);
                    config.set("Combo", comboMode);
                    config.set("fireball.destroyBlocks", destroyBlocks);
                    config.set("fireball.fallDamage", fallDamage);

                    saveConfig();

                    sender.sendMessage(
                            ChatColor.GREEN + "Fireball settings updated: " + " set vertical:" + verticalKnockback + " set horizontal:" + horizontalKnockback + " set Speed:" + Speed + " set Power:" + Power + " set Incendiary:" + Incendiary + " set ComboMode:" + comboMode + " set DestroyBlocks:" + destroyBlocks + " set FallDamage:" + fallDamage
                    );
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid value! Please enter the correct number!");
                }
            } else {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Command usage: /fireball <horizontalKnockback> <verticalKnockback> <Speed> <Power> <Incendiary (true or false)> <ComboMode (true or false)> <DestroyBlocks (true or false)> <FallDamage (true or false)>");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void setMaxNoDamageTicks(boolean comboMode) {
        int ticks = comboMode ? 2 : 11;
        for (World world : Bukkit.getWorlds()) {
            for (LivingEntity entity : world.getLivingEntities()) {
                entity.setMaximumNoDamageTicks(ticks);
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamagebyEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
        if (event.getDamager() instanceof Fireball && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
            Fireball fireball = (Fireball) event.getDamager();
            LivingEntity livingEntity = (Player) event.getEntity();
            livingEntity.damage(0, fireball);
            Vector fireballVelocity = fireball.getVelocity().normalize();
            Vector knockbackVector = new Vector(
                    fireballVelocity.getX() * horizontalKnockback,
                    fireballVelocity.getY() * (verticalKnockback * -1),
                    fireballVelocity.getZ() * horizontalKnockback
            );
            livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);

            if (livingEntity.getLocation().distanceSquared(fireball.getLocation()) <= fireball.getYield() * fireball.getYield()) {
                livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
            }

            event.setDamage(0.0);
        } else if (event.getDamager() instanceof TNTPrimed && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
            if (event.getDamager() instanceof Fireball && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
                TNTPrimed tntPrimed = (TNTPrimed) event.getDamager();
                LivingEntity livingEntity = (Player) event.getEntity();
                livingEntity.damage(0, tntPrimed);
                Vector fireballVelocity = tntPrimed.getVelocity().normalize();
                Vector knockbackVector = new Vector(
                        fireballVelocity.getX() * horizontalKnockback,
                        fireballVelocity.getY() * (verticalKnockback* -1),
                        fireballVelocity.getZ() * horizontalKnockback
                );
                livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
                if (livingEntity.getLocation().distanceSquared(tntPrimed.getLocation()) <= tntPrimed.getYield() * tntPrimed.getYield()) {
                    livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
                }
            }
            event.setDamage(0.0);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onProjectileHit(ProjectileHitEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.FIREBALL) {
            Fireball fireball = (Fireball) event.getEntity();
            if (fireball.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player shooter = (Player) fireball.getShooter();

                Location explosionLocation = fireball.getLocation();
                if (shooter.getLocation().distance(explosionLocation) <= 1.5) {
                    Vector selfKnockback = shooter.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(Speed * horizontalKnockback);
                    selfKnockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                    shooter.setVelocity(selfKnockback);
                }

                for (Entity entity : explosionLocation.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(explosionLocation, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)) {
                    if (entity instanceof Player) {
                        Player target = (Player) entity;
                        if (!target.getUniqueId().equals(shooter.getUniqueId())) {
                            Vector knockback = target.getLocation().toVector().subtract(explosionLocation.toVector()).normalize().multiply(Speed * horizontalKnockback);
                            knockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                            target.setVelocity(knockback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.WITHER_SKULL) {
            WitherSkull witherSkull = (WitherSkull) event.getEntity();
            if (witherSkull.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player shooter = (Player) witherSkull.getShooter();

                Location explosionLocation = witherSkull.getLocation();
                if (shooter.getLocation().distance(explosionLocation) <= 1.5) {
                    Vector selfKnockback = shooter.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(1 * horizontalKnockback);
                    selfKnockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                    shooter.setVelocity(selfKnockback);
                }

                for (Entity entity : explosionLocation.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(explosionLocation, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)) {
                    if (entity instanceof Player) {
                        Player target = (Player) entity;
                        if (!target.getUniqueId().equals(shooter.getUniqueId())) {
                            Vector knockback = target.getLocation().toVector().subtract(explosionLocation.toVector()).normalize().multiply(1 * horizontalKnockback);
                            knockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                            target.setVelocity(knockback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[sub program]:

```java
package com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.BlockExplode;


import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.block.BlockState;
import org.bukkit.entity.Fireball;
import org.bukkit.entity.TNTPrimed;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import org.bukkit.Material;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BlockReset extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    final Map<EntityExplodeEvent, Map<Block, BlockData>> explosionsData = new HashMap<>();

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityExplode(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof TNTPrimed || event.getEntity() instanceof org.bukkit.entity.WitherSkull || event.getEntity() instanceof Fireball) {
            saveBlockData(event);
            restoreBlocksLater(event);
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void saveBlockData(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        Map<Block, BlockData> blockDataBackup = new HashMap<>();
        for (Block block : event.blockList()) {
            BlockState blockState = block.getState();
            BlockData blockData = new BlockData(blockState.getType(), blockState.getData().getData());
            blockDataBackup.put(block, blockData);
        }
        this.explosionsData.put(event, blockDataBackup);
    }

    private void restoreBlocksLater(final EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        (new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                BlockReset.this.restoreBlocks(event);
            }
        }).runTaskLater(this, 60L);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void restoreBlocks(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (this.explosionsData.containsKey(event)) {
            Map<Block, BlockData> blockDataBackup = this.explosionsData.get(event);
            for (Block block : event.blockList()) {
                if (blockDataBackup.containsKey(block)) {
                    BlockData blockData = blockDataBackup.get(block);
                    block.setType(blockData.getType());
                    block.setData(blockData.getData());
                    block.getState().update(true, false);
                }
            }
            this.explosionsData.remove(event);
        }
    }

    private static class BlockData {
        private final Material type;

        private final byte data;

        public BlockData(Material type, byte data) {
            this.type = type;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Material getType() {
            return this.type;
        }

        public byte getData() {
            return this.data;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried write them together , it works.
But it will make the program looks very complex.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**I see multiple issues or at least a couple of them are things I wouldn't handle that way.**

### 1. Listener Convention

Normally to register listeners you write

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listener(), this);
```

Most likely it doesn't hurt anything to do it the way you are. It's just convention. It's probably best to stick with convention.

### 2. Plugin Instance Issues - I am certain this is causing the problem

**ONLY** extend the class from `JavaPlugin` in the **main** class. **DO NOT** extend it anywhere else. This means get rid of `extends JavaPlugin` in your `BlockReset` class. If you do this, you're basically making two plugins inside your one JAR. I don't think that will work. :)

I see why you make the `BlockReset` class extend `JavaPlugin` now. You need instances of your plugin. To do this *properly* add the following to your main class:

```
// So you can get the plugin
public static FireballPlugin getPlugin() {
        return plugin;
    }

// This creates the plugin object
public static FireballPlugin plugin;
```

Also, add this in the `onEnable` in your main class:

```
// This assigns the plugin object to the class
plugin = this;
```

That should be the first thing in your `onEnable`. What this does is make it so can do

```
FireballPlugin.getplugin()
```

instead of trying to use `JavaPlugin` and `this` whenever you need a plugin instance in your `BlockReset` class now.

Replace the `this` in the `BlockReset` class here

```
private void restoreBlocksLater(final EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        (new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Also fix these type of things
                BlockReset.this.restoreBlocks(event);
            }
        // Right here    |
        //               V
        }).runTaskLater(this, 60L);
    }
```

The improved version of that method would be

```
private void restoreBlocksLater(final EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        (new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                // This method is within the same class
                restoreBlocks(event);
            }
        // This is the way to do it!
        }).runTaskLater(FireballPlugin.getPlugin(), 60L);
    }
```

Get rid of all those other this'es. You don't need that because Java knows you're talking about a variable or method in that class. If you were talking about a variable in another class you would put `OtherClass.variable`. The only reason `this.whatever` exists is for constructors.

### 3. Artifact Naming Convention

Normally the plugin folder is in lower caps. That's not a big deal at all, but it's also convention. If you're using a build system, which you should be, you must make it in lower caps. I don't think you can use one with capitals in the artifact name. If you're using the IDE called IntelliJ and the `Minecraft Development` plugin, it's all automatically made.

The layout should normally be `com.example.yourplugin.YourPlugin`, so like this: `com.badlyac.newfireballplugin.FireballPlugin`.

But, you have it like this: `com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.FireballPlugin`.

## Fixed classes

Here are your fixed classes by just fixing the first two issues. You can decide whether to fix the third issue or not.

Main class:

```
package com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin;

import com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.BlockExplode.BlockReset;
import com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.PlayerResistance.AntiFire;
import org.bukkit.*;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.*;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.ProjectileHitEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;

// Only place JavaPlugin should be used
public class FireballPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    // So you can get the plugin
    public static FireballPlugin getPlugin() {
        return plugin;
    }

    // This creates the plugin object
    public static FireballPlugin plugin;

    private double horizontalKnockback;
    private double verticalKnockback;
    private double Speed;
    private int Power;
    private boolean Incendiary;
    private boolean comboMode;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private boolean destroyBlocks;
    private boolean fallDamage;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // This assigns the plugin object to this class
        plugin = this;
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new GiveItemWhenJoin(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new AntiFire(),this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockReset(),this);
        loadConfig();
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "FireballPlugin has been enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info(ChatColor.RED + "FireballPlugin has been disabled!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void Fireball(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.FIREBALL) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection().normalize();
                    Fireball fireball = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), Fireball.class);
                    fireball.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    fireball.setShooter(player);
                    fireball.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                    fireball.setYield(1 + Power);
                }
            }
        }


        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.FIREBALL && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void SmallFireball(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BLAZE_POWDER) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection();
                    SmallFireball smallFireball = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), SmallFireball.class);
                    smallFireball.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    smallFireball.setShooter(player);
                    smallFireball.setYield(Power);
                    smallFireball.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                }
            }
        }

        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.BLAZE_POWDER && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void WitherSKull(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.SKULL_ITEM) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    Location loc = player.getLocation();
                    Vector dir = loc.getDirection();
                    WitherSkull witherSkull = player.getWorld().spawn(loc.add(0, 1.6, 0), WitherSkull.class);
                    witherSkull.setVelocity(dir.multiply(0.5 + Speed));
                    witherSkull.setShooter(player);
                    witherSkull.setYield(Power);
                    witherSkull.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
                }
            }
        }

        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.SKULL_ITEM && player.getItemInHand().getDurability() == 1&& player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }


    @EventHandler
    public void onTntLaunch(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")) {
            Material heldMaterial = getHeldMaterial(player);
            if (heldMaterial == Material.TNT) {
                if(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
                    TNT(player);
                    event.setCancelled(true);
                }
            }
        }
        Material material = player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType();
        if (material == Material.TNT && player.hasPermission("fireball.admin")){
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
    private Material getHeldMaterial(Player player) {
        ItemStack heldItem = player.getItemInHand();
        return heldItem.getType();
    }

    private void TNT(Player player) {
        TNTPrimed tnt = player.getWorld().spawn(player.getLocation(), TNTPrimed.class);
        tnt.setFuseTicks(50);
        double tntSpeed = 1.3;
        tnt.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(tntSpeed));
        tnt.setYield(1 + Power);
        tnt.setIsIncendiary(Incendiary);
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof TNTPrimed) {
            handleTNTExplosion(event);
        } else if (event.getEntity() instanceof Fireball) {
            handleFireballExplosion(event);
        } else if(event.getEntity() instanceof WitherSkull){
            handleWitherSkullExplosion(event);
        }
    }

    private void handleTNTExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }

    private void handleFireballExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }
    private void handleWitherSkullExplosion(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (!destroyBlocks) {
            event.blockList().clear();
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof Player && event.getCause() == EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause.FALL) {
            if (!fallDamage) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadConfig() {

        saveDefaultConfig();

        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();

        horizontalKnockback = config.getDouble("fireball.knockback.horizontalKnockback",5.0);
        verticalKnockback = config.getDouble("fireball.knockback.verticalKnockback",-2.5);
        Speed =config.getDouble("fireball.Speed",1.5);
        Power = config.getInt("fireball.Power",3);
        Incendiary = config.getBoolean("fireball.Incendiary",false);
        comboMode = config.getBoolean("Combo",false);
        destroyBlocks = config.getBoolean("fireball.destroyBlocks" , false);
        fallDamage = config.getBoolean("fallDamage", false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("fireball")) {
            if (args.length == 8) {
                try {
                    double f1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
                    double f2 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
                    double f3 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
                    int f4 = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
                    boolean f5 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[4]);
                    boolean f6 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[5]);
                    boolean f7 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[6]);
                    boolean f8 = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[7]);

                    horizontalKnockback = f1;
                    verticalKnockback = f2;
                    Speed = f3;
                    Power = f4;
                    Incendiary = f5;
                    comboMode = f6;
                    destroyBlocks = f7;
                    fallDamage = f8;

                    setMaxNoDamageTicks(comboMode);

                    FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
                    config.set("fireball.knockback.horizontalKnockback", horizontalKnockback);
                    config.set("fireball.knockback.verticalKnockback", verticalKnockback);
                    config.set("fireball.Speed", Speed);
                    config.set("fireball.Power", Power);
                    config.set("fireball.Incendiary", Incendiary);
                    config.set("Combo", comboMode);
                    config.set("fireball.destroyBlocks", destroyBlocks);
                    config.set("fireball.fallDamage", fallDamage);

                    saveConfig();

                    sender.sendMessage(
                            ChatColor.GREEN + "Fireball settings updated: " + " set vertical:" + verticalKnockback + " set horizontal:" + horizontalKnockback + " set Speed:" + Speed + " set Power:" + Power + " set Incendiary:" + Incendiary + " set ComboMode:" + comboMode + " set DestroyBlocks:" + destroyBlocks + " set FallDamage:" + fallDamage
                    );
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Invalid value! Please enter the correct number!");
                }
            } else {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Command usage: /fireball <horizontalKnockback> <verticalKnockback> <Speed> <Power> <Incendiary (true or false)> <ComboMode (true or false)> <DestroyBlocks (true or false)> <FallDamage (true or false)>");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void setMaxNoDamageTicks(boolean comboMode) {
        int ticks = comboMode ? 2 : 11;
        for (World world : Bukkit.getWorlds()) {
            for (LivingEntity entity : world.getLivingEntities()) {
                entity.setMaximumNoDamageTicks(ticks);
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamagebyEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
        if (event.getDamager() instanceof Fireball && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
            Fireball fireball = (Fireball) event.getDamager();
            LivingEntity livingEntity = (Player) event.getEntity();
            livingEntity.damage(0, fireball);
            Vector fireballVelocity = fireball.getVelocity().normalize();
            Vector knockbackVector = new Vector(
                    fireballVelocity.getX() * horizontalKnockback,
                    fireballVelocity.getY() * (verticalKnockback * -1),
                    fireballVelocity.getZ() * horizontalKnockback
            );
            livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);

            if (livingEntity.getLocation().distanceSquared(fireball.getLocation()) <= fireball.getYield() * fireball.getYield()) {
                livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
            }

            event.setDamage(0.0);
        } else if (event.getDamager() instanceof TNTPrimed && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
            if (event.getDamager() instanceof Fireball && event.getEntity() instanceof LivingEntity) {
                TNTPrimed tntPrimed = (TNTPrimed) event.getDamager();
                LivingEntity livingEntity = (Player) event.getEntity();
                livingEntity.damage(0, tntPrimed);
                Vector fireballVelocity = tntPrimed.getVelocity().normalize();
                Vector knockbackVector = new Vector(
                        fireballVelocity.getX() * horizontalKnockback,
                        fireballVelocity.getY() * (verticalKnockback* -1),
                        fireballVelocity.getZ() * horizontalKnockback
                );
                livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
                if (livingEntity.getLocation().distanceSquared(tntPrimed.getLocation()) <= tntPrimed.getYield() * tntPrimed.getYield()) {
                    livingEntity.setVelocity(knockbackVector);
                }
            }
            event.setDamage(0.0);
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onProjectileHit(ProjectileHitEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.FIREBALL) {
            Fireball fireball = (Fireball) event.getEntity();
            if (fireball.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player shooter = (Player) fireball.getShooter();

                Location explosionLocation = fireball.getLocation();
                if (shooter.getLocation().distance(explosionLocation) <= 1.5) {
                    Vector selfKnockback = shooter.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(Speed * horizontalKnockback);
                    selfKnockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                    shooter.setVelocity(selfKnockback);
                }

                for (Entity entity : explosionLocation.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(explosionLocation, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)) {
                    if (entity instanceof Player) {
                        Player target = (Player) entity;
                        if (!target.getUniqueId().equals(shooter.getUniqueId())) {
                            Vector knockback = target.getLocation().toVector().subtract(explosionLocation.toVector()).normalize().multiply(Speed * horizontalKnockback);
                            knockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                            target.setVelocity(knockback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getEntityType() == EntityType.WITHER_SKULL) {
            WitherSkull witherSkull = (WitherSkull) event.getEntity();
            if (witherSkull.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player shooter = (Player) witherSkull.getShooter();

                Location explosionLocation = witherSkull.getLocation();
                if (shooter.getLocation().distance(explosionLocation) <= 1.5) {
                    Vector selfKnockback = shooter.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(1 * horizontalKnockback);
                    selfKnockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                    shooter.setVelocity(selfKnockback);
                }

                for (Entity entity : explosionLocation.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(explosionLocation, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5)) {
                    if (entity instanceof Player) {
                        Player target = (Player) entity;
                        if (!target.getUniqueId().equals(shooter.getUniqueId())) {
                            Vector knockback = target.getLocation().toVector().subtract(explosionLocation.toVector()).normalize().multiply(1 * horizontalKnockback);
                            knockback.setY(verticalKnockback);
                            target.setVelocity(knockback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sub-program:

```
package com.badlyac.NewFireballPlugin.BlockExplode;

import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.block.BlockState;
import org.bukkit.entity.Fireball;
import org.bukkit.entity.TNTPrimed;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;
import org.bukkit.Material;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// No JavaPlugin allowed here!
public class BlockReset implements Listener {

    final Map<EntityExplodeEvent, Map<Block, BlockData>> explosionsData = new HashMap<>();

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityExplode(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof TNTPrimed || event.getEntity() instanceof org.bukkit.entity.WitherSkull || event.getEntity() instanceof Fireball) {
            saveBlockData(event);
            restoreBlocksLater(event);
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void saveBlockData(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        Map<Block, BlockData> blockDataBackup = new HashMap<>();
        for (Block block : event.blockList()) {
            BlockState blockState = block.getState();
            BlockData blockData = new BlockData(blockState.getType(), blockState.getData().getData());
            blockDataBackup.put(block, blockData);
        }
        // No this'es
        explosionsData.put(event, blockDataBackup);
    }

    private void restoreBlocksLater(final EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        (new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Get rid of Class.this
                restoreBlocks(event);
            }
        // Plugin instance issue fixed here
        }).runTaskLater(FireballPlugin.getPlugin(), 60L);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void restoreBlocks(EntityExplodeEvent event) {
        if (this.explosionsData.containsKey(event)) {
            // Got rid of a this
            Map<Block, BlockData> blockDataBackup = explosionsData.get(event);
            for (Block block : event.blockList()) {
                if (blockDataBackup.containsKey(block)) {
                    BlockData blockData = blockDataBackup.get(block);
                    block.setType(blockData.getType());
                    block.setData(blockData.getData());
                    block.getState().update(true, false);
                }
            }
            // Got rid of a this
            explosionsData.remove(event);
        }
    }

    private static class BlockData {
        private final Material type;

        private final byte data;

        public BlockData(Material type, byte data) {
            // Now this is where those this'es go
            this.type = type;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Material getType() {
            // No this needed here
            return type;
        }

        public byte getData() {
            // Not here either
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Sheese, that's a lot of writing. Hope that fixes your problem and clears things up!